podman inter container communication
podman inter container communication not possible

icmp between container possible
telnet/curl to tcp:3000 not possible
one container part of podman-compose (tcp:3000), other one part of pod (tcp:445) ... unfortunately both are in different networks
ports definitely exposed
no firewall enabled
selinux permissive

Problem occurs since last dnf update (alma) of podman and nmcli.
tried to
... put all container in one pod - not easy with podman compose
... put all container in same network
